# C# Should I use CertUtil to compute hash of a zip file

Tags: c#, cmd

Answer might be a bit opinion-based but really important to me as I am pretty sure that `certutil` is accurate. Not sure for c# MD5 class.

I have a zip file and to verify if it's correct, I want to find its MD5 hash value. This is to then extract the zip file and use its contents in my C# .Net Framework 4.8 console application.

I have currently asked clients (each client has a my men appointed for tech support) to use `CertUtil -hashfile` command to get the hash and verify it but now, I guess due to increase in clients, I must automate it in my app and give a relief to my men.

I am confused should I use `CertUtil` and get the output in a C# string using `Process.Start()` or should i use the .net framework's MD5 class.

C# app is deployed only on windows 10 and I have administrative access to it so not finding `certutil` isn't an excuse.

Using CertUtil it will be something like this:

```
    public static bool check_correct_installation()
        {
            var md5Checksum = "";
            var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                FileName = "cmd.exe",
                Arguments = $"/C  CertUtil -hashfile \"{HolocronFolders["Root"]}\" MD5 | find /i /v \"md5\" | find /i /v \"certutil\"",
            };
            using var process = new Process {StartInfo = startInfo};
            process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) => md5Checksum = e.Data;
            process.Start();
            
            var fileToRead = $"{HolocronFolders["Council"]}\\force.sith";
            if (!File.Exists(fileToRead)) return false;
            var sithForce = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SithForce>(File.ReadAllText(fileToRead));
            return sithForce != null && sithForce.Checksum.Md5.ToString() != md5Checksum.Trim();
        }
```

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Sorry I meant 4.8

Comment: I think if you're finding that the C# MD5 classes aren't generating the hash value you're expecting, then you've probably done something wrong.... What results are you getting that make you doubt them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, opinion based, but still here is mine:

Well, you're launching 4(!) processes for each signature you create (cmd.exe, certutil.exe and 2x find.exe). That alone would drag me away from it.

Then, the MD5 classes are being used in a multitude of applications projects, I would say there is no objective way to distrust them, unless you have a proven example where they were "wrong" or an security advisory, etc. that says so.

Finally, the `MD5` implementation uses the underlying Windows API (see [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Security/Cryptography/BCryptHashAlgorithm.cs,d76048c32dd4fab0) to look into the rabbit whole) anyway. So chances are that it uses the same code (in the end) aus CertUtil.exe.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, this might be an opinion-based answer, however I don't see many issues with sticking to your use as you stated with the code. Searching on the internet, it seems that other people chose similar approach, too. Give it a try!